# Teamviewer deauthorize computer

Tags: teamviewer

I had to use my account for teamviewer in public place.
I have double authorization enabled, so I had to authorize device from my email before I could log in from this computer.

Because it was public computer I would want to deauthorize this computer, so next logins from this computer would require me to authorize device from my email again.

I was searching in google and on teamviewer page, however I found nothing which would help me.

Is it even possible to deauthorize device in teamviewer, or once authorised device will be always authorised? I guess that computer doesnt deauthorize after signing out of account.

Comment: Your answer is contained with the [manual](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/support/documents/)